# How to Implement Language switcher in popup before loading my home page in joomla 3

Tags: popup, joomla3.0

Can anyone help me to show the language switcher in popup before loading my site home page in **Joomla 3**

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this, but maybe you can make a copy of your template as your landing page with no content or default language landing page. 
Then you can hardcode the popup right in the template.

( http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp ) 
But I'm not sure whether this is a good idea or not, cause of f.e. popup-blockers or revisitting. 
If you have an "all languages" landing page you probably fix the revisit problem (with linked language landing pages).